# Скорость сходимости итерационного процесса

Tags: матрицы, численные-методы

Означает ли бОльшая скорость сходимости одного итерационного метода решения СЛАУ (по сравнению с другим итерационным методом) строго меньшее число необходимых шагов для получения результата?

Например, решение стационарным методом Зейделя системы 5x5 потребовало 8 шагов, а нестационарным (для которого заявлена бОльшая скорость сходимости) - 11 шагов. Возможно ли это или следует искать ошибку в программной реализации последнего?

Comment: Скорость решения системы 5 на 5 не говорит ни о чём. Её можно в лоб решить методом Крамера вообще без шагов. Обсуждать скорость сходимости можно, начиная с размерностей эдак 100 на 100, причём заранее нужно договориться о том, какое семейство систем рассматривается - например, трёх/пяти диагональные, разреженные, плотные. Или ввести ограничения на норму матрицы и спектральный радиус. Как-то так.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, это абсолютно возможно и нормально.

Есть такое выражение, что всегда (не уверен, что в строго математическом смысле) можно подобрать пример, для которого один итерационный метод решения систем линейных уравнений работает лучше чем другой, особенно если эти методы из разных семейств.

Если продолжить увеличивать требования к критерию сходимости, метод с большей скоростью сходимости начнет обгонять более медленный по сходимости метод. То есть, например, для решения системы с точностью `10^(-3)` методу Зейделя потребовалось 8 шагов, а другому методу — 11. Тогда как для `10^(-5)` ситуация уже будет в пользу "более продвинутого" метода. Или для `10^(-7)`.

**Итого:** выводы о сходимости итерационного процесса и качеству реализации метода в программном коде на основе одного эксперимента с фиксированной заданной точностью решения делать нельзя.

**Рекомендации:** а) попробовать посмотреть что будет для более строгих требований к точности
б) увеличить немножко матрицу. `5х5` это все же несерьезно. Хотя скорее всего нормально.
в) попробовать это не на случайно взятой матрице, а на матрицах, которыми пользуются для тестирования методов линейной алгебры, в том числе и итеративных методов решения линейных систем уравнений (например, [Matrix Market](https://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/)).

---

NB: существуют ситуации, когда итеративный метод, который имеет лучшую сходимость, имеет более высокие требования к обусловленности системы ([число обусловления](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)), [предобуславливателям](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) ([preconditioner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preconditioner)), или правая часть лежит в "очень нехорошем подпространстве". Такие вещи происходят, но чаще на искусственных примерах.